# Async attribute results in jQuery undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

According to the [slides](http://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=http%3a%2f%2fvideo.ch9.ms%2fsessions%2fbuild%2f2012%2f3-132.pptx) of [50 performance tricks to make your HTML5 apps and sites faster](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-132) on Channel 9 MSDN, it is suggested that we need to use `async` attribute in `script` tag.

Now, I have following markup in my document (just before closing `body` tag):

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.0.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" async></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.migrate/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" async></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript" async></script>
```

In console, (one out of every 10  page loads) IE11's console shows:

> [SCRIPT5009](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(VS.WebClient.Help.SCRIPT5009)): 'jQuery' is undefined
>
> File: jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js, Line: 2, Column: 1

How to prevent this from happening when using `async` attribute?

Comment: `async` doesn't sound like a good idea if you have scripts that depend on each other (like `jquery-migrate` depends on `jquery`). Perhaps leave `jquery` as is and just make the other two `async`.

Comment: Yes, "async" is a good idea when it's a good idea. This is not one of those times.